# What's the geometric meaning of the jacobian of a linear map?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given a linear map $f$ which maps triangle $T$ to another triangle $T^{'}$, what's the geometric meaning of the jacobian of $f$? Is it equal to the ratio of the area of $T^{'}$ to the area of $T$?
If the answer is yes. How to prove it?

Comment: Yes. At least if $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$ and you remember to take the absolute value.

Comment: For a linear map $f$, its Jacobian matrix at every point is just the matrix of $f$. So its Jacobian is simply the determinant of $f$.

Comment: If the answer is yes. How to prove it?

Comment: Use user49640’s observation. The rest is just a basic property of the determinant of a matrix.

Comment: I like the approach to the Jacobian in the book of Burago and Burago on metric geometry. The (absolute value of the) Jacobian is *defined* in terms of the change of variable formula for integrals. Then one proves that, in $\mathbb R^n$ with a Cartesian coordinate system, this Jacobian is the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one unorthodox way to see it. Let $x$ denote the original coordinate system and $f(x)=y$ be that of the deformed triangle. E.g. a triangle 
$(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ is mapped to $(f(p_1),f(p_2),f(p_3))=(q_1,q_2,q_3)$.

From a mechanics perspective, the Jacobian matrix of this transformation is [the deformation gradient](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics/Strains_and_deformations#Deformation_Gradient):
$$
F_{ij} = \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j}\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\;
F=\begin{bmatrix} \partial_1 f_1 & \partial_2 f_1 \\ \partial_1 f_2 & \partial_2 f_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$ 
It is [a long-known fact from continuum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_strain_theory#Transformation_of_a_surface_and_volume_element) that $J=\det(F)$ gives the change in area (volume in 3D) of a deformation.
See [here](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics/Volume_change_and_area_change), for instance, for a proof.

You can also view it from a change-of-variables perspective in integration.